# Deterministic order when using an order by random with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, random, sql-order-by

I'm using a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

All is well if the number of rows is low. In my tests however, I would like to have something reproducible to verify. This is why I'm seeding the random number generator:

```
SELECT setseed(0.123);
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY RANDOM();
```

It's nice and working well. It looks like the order is same time on each execution. Except that it's not completely reproducible. In some cases, the test succeeds and I get the expected order and result. In some execution of the same test, I don't. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

You might have better luck with a subquery:

```
SELECT setseed(0.123);
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT i.*, RANDOM() as rand
      items i
     ) i
ORDER BY rand;
```

The reason is that the function `RANDOM()` is called many times during the sorting.  Some sorting algorithms are non-deterministic -- and that affects downstream rows.

This isn't 100% guaranteed, because the subquery could still not be processed in order (although it should be on a single processor system).  But you can further rectify this by using a *hash* rather than a random value.  So:

```
order by md5(item_id || '0.123')
```

The `item_id` is assumed to be different on each row.  The `'0.123'` is the added so you can easily change the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is linked to the fact that rows are first fetched in an unspecified order (if no ORDER BY clause is specified), and only then is the RANDOM() function called for each row. This means that the unspecified order will impact the row order after the ORDER BY RANDOM() is applied.

Example, using the same seed in both cases:

case 1

```
SELECT * FROM items
returns
item_1
item_2
item_3
item_4

SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY RANDOM();
may return

item_3
item_4
item_1
item_2
```

case 2

```
SELECT * FROM items
returns
item_4
item_3
item_2
item_1

SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY RANDOM();
may return

item_2
item_1
item_4
item_3
```

The solution is then to order the rows before ordering them by RANDOM(). The end result is 100% deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a repeatable random sort.

`setseed()` is the correct approach, however you need to set it *within* the query, so it applies to all further invocations of `random()`.

Here is one solution using `union all`:

```
select item_id
from (
    select setseed(0.5), null item_id
    union all
    select null, item_id from items
    offset 1
) s
order by random()
```

This demonstrates how to proceed with a table that has only one column. You can extend this for more columns by adding more `null` columns to the first subquery (and accordingly listing the corresponding columns in the other `union all` member and in the outer query).